# Do I need forward declaration for a good message based communication system?

Tags: c++, architecture, design-patterns

I am thinking about a game engine like this:

[image: class diag]
I am trying to implement message-based communication. Every `ReceiveMessage()` method processes the `Message`, or forwards it into the right direction based on the messages `recipentType`. For example:

1. The `EngineCore` infinite loop sends render messages towards `Game`.
2. `Game` forwards the messages towards every `GameObject`.
3. `GameObject`s forward the messages towards their `RenderComponent`.
4. The `RenderComponent` must send its `RenderData` back to the `RenderEngine`.

As far as I know, this can only be implemented if the dependencies are bidirectional, which requires forward declaration. Is this possible in another way, or do I have to implement this in a "polling" way?

Comment: You're asking a couple of different questions. If you're asking about messaging, then the Component system question isn't relevant. Besides Components can be handled in many different ways, regardless of messaging or polling.

Plenty of frameworks may do polling, though I view messaging as a more efficient implementation, in terms of not wasting resources more than necessary. 

The message system you're trying to implement sounds like an event system will do. http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/game-programming/simple-event-handling-r2141

Comment: yep, that's what I want. Maybe dividing the engine to two parts, 1 with polling and 1 with events.
Then my question is: is it possible the implement this without bidirectional dependency (and so forward declaration)?

Comment: Which dependencies are you concerned with? The dependencies should be between the generic interfaces. The implementations shouldn't know anything about the implementations of the other interfaces, you'll only be working through the interfaces.

Comment: This seems to me to be a lot of messages sent to objects that don't care.

Comment: So I should make a Listener interface for every class which can ReceiveMessages? But if the only public method in the classes is the ReceiveMessaage, is there a difference? I mean the only difference is that the header files contain non-public things too, but they are inaccessible.

@AlexandreVaillancourt The only time this happens, is when for example a gameObject is looking for another gameObject, and that gameObject is at the end of the list. Then the message will go through all the other gameObjects. Is this a big problem?

Comment: IMHO, the engine core should have a direct reference to all of the graphics components and draw them direct. Same for the physics simulation. You _know_ that there will be a lot of processing for these 2 aspects, messaging does not seem to be the proper tool for that.

Comment: Then I have to store pointers to the render components. Isn't that breaks encapsulation?

Comment: Note that opinion-based questions are off topic. Removing that part from the question, we are left with the question regarding the need for forward declaration, so I have also edited the title.